# create json using JSONObject

Tags: string, gson

I have to create json string like below,

> {   "data": {
> "data": "message"   },   "status": "SUCCESS" }

I am using below code to create json string on the fly,

```
>         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
>         JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
>         try {
>             jsonData.put("data", "message");
>             jsonObject.put("data",jsonData);
>             jsonObject.put("status", "SUCCESS");
>             Log.d("AYadav", new Gson().toJson(jsonObject));
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
```

but from above code I am getting below json string,

> {   "nameValuePairs": {
> "data": {
> "nameValuePairs": {
> "data": "message"
> }
> },
> "status": "SUCCESS"   } }

Why extra nameValuePairs is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two JSON libraries, Gson and (I assume) JSON-java. `JSONObject` (with "JSON" completely uppercase) is not part of Gson, it belongs to JSON-java.

If you want to use Gson, then use its class [`com.google.gson.JsonObject`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and then at the end call `Gson.toJson`. Do not call `JsonObject.toString()` because its [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#toString()) currently makes no guarantees that the output will be the JSON document.

If you want to use JSON-java, then keep using the `JSONObject` class, but at the end call [`JSONObject.toString()`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString--).